# Elastic search string query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have database that looks like this:

{
"test": true,
"example": "string1"
}

Im using elasticsearch string query to get data that contains specific strings, but I need to filter it to get results that has false in 'test' attribute. Is there any way to do this by string query?

True and False values are not in quotes !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `query_string` query, you can do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "test:false AND example:foobar"
    }
  }
}
```

You can also do it outside of the `query_string` query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "test": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "example:foobar"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that 'true' and 'false' values are not in " quotes. So its not working.